# How do I generate a laplacian matrix for a graph dataset?

Tags: matrix

If I have a dataset in a csv that looks like the one shown below.

How do I convert this into a laplacian matrix using Python?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use SciPy's [Laplacian](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.1/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csgraph.laplacian.html) function:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse.csgraph import laplacian

g = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 1, 0, 1],
              [0, 0, 0, 1],
              [0, 1, 1, 1]])

laplacian(g)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well the `Laplacian` matrix is achieved by:

$degree (v_i) $ for $\space$ i=j

$-1$ for $\space$ if $v_j$ and $v_i$ are not adjacent to each other

$0$ otherwise

---

First, you need to store your file to a 2d-array
Then you need to define another 2d-array matrix the same size of your first matrix. Then loop over the elements to fill the `Laplacian` matrix

```py
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
df = pd.Dataframe(data)
M = df.as_matrix()
L = np.zeros(df.shape[0], df.shape[1]) #shape[0] and shape[1] should be equal
```

Then for each element $A_{i,j}$ we calculate their corresponding value in L

```py
for i in range(len(df.shape[0])):
    for j in range(len(df.shape[0])): # or shape[1]
        if M[i][j] == 0 and M[j][i]== 0:
            L[i][j] = -1
        if i == j:
            L[i][j] = sum(M[i][:])
        else:
            L[i][j] = 0
```

**I haven't tried the code so consider it much like a pseudo-code.**